# dice animation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm building a yatzy-game where I call a shuffle function to decide which dice to be shown.

```
$("#dice" + i).attr('src', 'img/Dice' + yatzyLogic.randomDice() + '.gif');
```

It works great but I want a animation when you throw the dice, something like **[this](http://efrane.github.com/jquery-dice/)**. But if I apply this I have to re-write dozens of code, and I'm lazy :).

Is there some easier way to apply that kind of thing to my code? Like a timer function that quickly shows different images?

Comment: being lazy , you should have thought about it before writing the code you now have to refactor

Comment: well I'm a newbie but I hear ya..

Comment: If you have to rewrite tons of code something is *very very* wrong with your code. That plugin has a super-easy and comfortable API. You just call the function and pass whatever function handles the dice roll results as a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>http://pannonicaquartet.com/test/ej_010_R.html</del> (404)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var spnResultado, imgDado, numero, timerReference, timeoutReference;
function init(){
 try{
    imgDado = document.getElementById("imgDado");
    spnResultado = document.getElementById("spnResultado");
 }catch(er){
    if(console.log)console.log("Error in init: " + er);
    if(spnResultado)spnResultado.innerText = "Error in init: " + er;
 }
}

function btnStartOnClick(){
 try{
    if(!timerReference){
        numero = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        timerReference = setInterval(timerFunction,13);
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*901)+800;
        setTimeout(timeoutFunction,rnd);
        spnResultado.innerText = "rnd " + rnd;
    }
 }catch(er){
    if(console.log)console.log("Error in btnStartOnClick: " + er);
    spnResultado.innerText = "Error in btnStartOnClick: " + er;
 }
}

function timerFunction(){
 try{
    numero++;
    if(numero > 6) numero = 1;
    var offsetImagen = -(numero-1) * 80;
    imgDado.style.marginLeft = offsetImagen + "px";
 }catch(er){
    if(console.log)console.log("Error in fnTimer:\n" + er);
 }
}

function timeoutFunction(){
 try{
    clearInterval(timerReference);
    timerReference = null;
    spnResultado.innerText = "Número: " + numero;
 }catch(er){
    if(console.log)console.log("Error in fnTimer:\n" + er);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create non-looping animated gifs for each dice value (*whose final frame will be the dice value ofcourse*)...

Not saying you should really do this (***i am actually suggesting you do not***), as it is just a trick..
But if you say you are unable/unwilling to re-code/re-factor your current code then i cannot see a different route..